# SimpleHTTPServer Custom Headers

Tags: python, http, http-headers, httpserver, simplehttpserver

By default SimpleHTTPServer sends it's own headers.

I've been trying to figure out how to send my own headers and found [this solution](https://gist.github.com/daimatz/3ca32ae11d9635372853). I tried adapting it to my (very) simple proxy:

```
import SocketServer
import SimpleHTTPServer
import urllib

class Proxy(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
  headers = ['Date: Wed, 29 Oct 2014 15:54:43 GMT', 'Server: Apache', 'Accept-Ranges: bytes', 'X-Mod-Pagespeed: 1.6.29.7-3566', 'Vary: Accept-Encoding', 'Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache', 'Content-Length: 204', 'Connection: close', 'Content-Type: text/html']

  def end_headers(self):
    print "Setting custom headers"
    self.custom_headers()

    SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.end_headers(self)

  def custom_headers(self):
    for i in self.headers:
      key, value = i.split(":", 1)
      self.send_header(key, value)

  def do_GET(self):
      self.copyfile(urllib.urlopen(self.path), self.wfile)

httpd = SocketServer.ForkingTCPServer(('', PORT), Proxy)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

But `end_headers()` doesn't set the custom headers (confirmed on Wireshark).

Given a list of `headers` like the one in my little snippet, how I can overwrite `SimpleHTTPServer's` default headers and server my own?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22308786/python-simplehttpserver-change-response-header/22309792#22309792)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss something in `do_GET()`.
`SimpleHTTPServer` also calls

- `self.send_response(200)`

See the following code or better the module `SimpleHTTPServer`

```
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", ctype)
        fs = os.fstat(f.fileno())
        self.send_header("Content-Length", str(fs[6]))
        self.send_header("Last-Modified", self.date_time_string(fs.st_mtime))
        self.end_headers()
```

I think you should override the `send_head()` method for what you want to do and read the source of `SimpleHTTPServer`.